# TortoiseHg crashes when trying to open settings in the file menu

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When I try to open setting under the file menu, I get the following crash:

```
#!python
** Mercurial version (4.2+4).  TortoiseHg version (4.2)
** Command: 
** CWD: C:\Windows\system32
** Encoding: cp1252
** Extensions loaded: 
** Python version: 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Windows version: sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1')
** Processor architecture: x64
** Qt-4.8.7 PyQt-4.11.4 QScintilla-2.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\workbench.pyo", line 1146, in editSettings
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\settings.pyo", line 1227, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'userrcpath'
```

TortoiseHg doesn't close if I just press OK, but I can't access my settings.

The only thing I did was re-install TortoiseHg (upgraded to the latest version 4.2). I experimented a little bit yesterday, and when I put my old Mercurial.ini file under C:/Users// and try to re-open Tortoise, it completely crashes and doesn't even let me open the program at all. Once I delete the file, I can open tortoise but not access settings.

I'm not sure what could be causing this problem. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

Edit: Tried re-installing again, but still seems to have the problem. I noticed that my old repos are still on the list when I uninstall. Is there a temp directory where these are stored that I can delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems like this was a problem with TortoiseHg 4.2. I downgraded to 4.1.3 and am able to get into my settings again. Still not entirely sure why the upgrade broke settings on my computer but I'm ok with 4.1.3.

Comment: Older versions can be downloaded here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug in the 4.2 release:

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4744/exception-while-openning-global-repo

It looks like they already have a fix in the pipeline.